# Android OpenCV imwrite No Implementation Found

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to use Imgcodecs.imwrite in my OpenCV Android application but it keeps giving my the error:

```
No implementation found for boolean org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imwrite_1(java.lang.String, long) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imwrite_11 and Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imwrite_11__Ljava_lang_String_2J)
```

My code is:

```
 private void takePhoto(final Mat rgba) {


        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mBgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);

        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "myFile.jpg";

        imageFile = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(imageFile.toString(), mBgr);


        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LabActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(LabActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO_DATA_PATH,
                imageFile.toString());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using? For older version you need `Highgui.imwrite`

Comment: Latest, 3.1. I've been stuck for hours...

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved it. The version should be declared as follows:

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0,
```